# How to disable automatic HTTPS redirect in IIS / Project

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, redirect, https

I want to cancel an https URL which is redirect in the request in the server because I can't load CSS and the jQuery file from that website.

For more clear let's elaborate the question,

I have created a login page containing CSS and jQuery file in aspx page(.net c#).

In local CSS and jQuery file is responding very well and it shows like above image

[image]

Now, when I publish the project and upload in server then same CSS and jQuery file is not **affecting** and it shows like

[image]

Now in live when I check by inspect element and from network option I know that it redirecting https in the place of http url and from that only project containing CSS and jQuery file is not loading.

Here is the inspect element image URL

[image: inspect element image url]

For testing you can use my live staging site url : **http://demo1aapp-001-site1.dtempurl.com/login**

And so from that I want to cancel the https and redirect to http

Comment: this is something to do with PLESK on server - you have plesk right ?

Comment: no. I am using smarterasp

Comment: Look for rewrite rules that adds this auto redirect from http to https